# Annoying tomcat warning about ThreadLocal

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, classloader

I've been meaning to ask this for a while. Does anyone see an issue with the following,

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(CONFIG_FILE);
```

I use this input stream to load a properties file into a java.util.Properties object which works just fine.

What I'm unsure of is why Tomcat 6 has issue with this, I'm not holding onto the classloader reference so why does it give the warning...

> SEVERE: The web application [/example] created a ThreadLocal with key
>   of type [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ClassFactory$1] (value
>   [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ClassFactory$1@4ae1da40]) and a value of type
>   [java.util.WeakHashMap] (value [{class
>   javax.xml.bind.annotation.W3CDomHandler=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@31bfc628}])
>   but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is
>   very likely to create a memory leak. Jan 27, 2013 6:18:34 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar deleteDir

This isn't the biggest problem in the world as I do not hot redploy my application, however I would like to know if I'm doing something inappropriate.

Many Thanks,

J

Comment: Just out of interest, where does the `STATIC_FILE` reference come from? Does the class, containing this reference, get undeployed?

Comment: Have you checked [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788280/memory-leak-when-redeploying-application-in-tomcat)?