# How to solve Metaspace OOM after redeploying a web application in Tomcat multiple times?

Tags: java, out-of-memory, tomcat8, metaspace

Dera all,

I am using openjdk 1.8.0_212-b04, Tomcat 8.0.21 and Red Hat 6.4.

And I have adjusted the test web application, make sure there will be **no such message** after redeploying it:

```
WARNING: The web application [Test] appears to have started a thread named [test-job_Worker-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread
```

Here is the GC parameter I have used in the test:

```
-Xms2G -Xmx4G 
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1G -XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize=300 

-Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=9223372036854775807 
-Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=9223372036854775807 
-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:GCLogFile Size=10M -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -Xloggc:$LOG_HOME/gc-$START_TIME.log
```

And I used a shell script, to keep touching the web.xml to redeploy the web application. There were no other traffics/operations during the test.

Here is the metaspace graph of VisualVM during the test:
[image]

As the figure shows: at point 1, the metaspace would shrink at sometime, so I think there should be no metaspace memory leak.

But at point 2, the Tomcat throws metaspace OOM:

```
14-Jun-2019 09:26:32.184 SEVERE [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run Unexpected death of background thread ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2472)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:854)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1274)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.status.StatusLogger.<init>(StatusLogger.java:108)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.status.StatusLogger.<clinit>(StatusLogger.java:85)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContextListener.<clinit>(Log4jServletContextListener.java:44)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
```

At point 3, I clicked the GC button in the VisualVM, the metaspace was actually shrinkable.

I have tried to add parameter: -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=60, but still got the smae result.

Here is the metaspace graph of GCeasy:
[image]

Here is the GC Log:
[GC Log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rs2t1Q8nZ9ZR-gDe67ZcaMDyxKoV3XSm/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks for any advice to solve/troubleshooting/debug the OOM error.

Update 1:
Thanks for @samabcde's suggestion, I added se.jiderhamn.classloader.leak.prevention.ClassLoaderLeakPreventor to do more tests.
It helps to remove some ThreadLocal variables and make the web application to hold on more time.

```
14-Jun-2019 17:44:31.463 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] se.jiderhamn.classloader.leak.prevention.JULLogger.info Custom ThreadLocal of type org.springframework.core.NamedThreadLocal: Prototype beans currently in creation with value null will be remove()d from Thread[ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]],5,main]
```

But still got the Metaspace OOM.
[image]

Comment: Did you try solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788280/memory-leak-when-redeploying-application-in-tomcat)?

Comment: @samabcde: Thanks, I tried and I have updated my post.

Answer (score 6):

During a test, I saw the Metaspace almost hit the max, then I stopped to redeploy the web application, and made a heap dump, put it under MAT to analyze.

As expected, there are many WebappClassLoader.
But I checked it's *Path To GC Roots | exclude all phatom/weak/soft. etc references*, it is it's GC Root.

I checked it's *Path to GC Roots | with all references*, then there are more then one GC Roots.
[image]

So... those WebappClassLoader are actually phatom/weak/soft. referenced by other objects, it would stay in the heap some time to be released.

Then I add the GC parameter: -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=10, the web application can be redeployed more then 1000 times...

So the problem is solved!

PS. since we will not redeploy the web application in a short time in the production environment, we will not use -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=10.